# Sending email contents as HTML in WSO2 ESB

Tags: wso2

**Success Email**
Email SUBJECT : [ENV] Details of the message(process name)
Ex : [DEV] : WSO2 ESB INFO : XXXX_UpdatePromotionHeaderProxy Completed

DateTime : 
Transaction ID :
Process Name :
File Name :

**Error Email**
Email SUBJECT : [ENV] Details of the message(process name)
Ex : [DEV] : WSO2 ESB ERROR : UpdatePromotionHeaderProxy FAILED

DateTime : 
Transaction ID :
Process Name :
File Name : 
Error Code : 
Error Description : 
Error Stack Trace :